# How to parse url parameters in key:value format?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

For example i have an url like this: `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cUjfXWuZySE&list=cUjfXWuZySE`. I need to parse its parameters in `key:value` format.

Currently i do it like this `params = re.findall('([^?=&]+)(?:[&#]|=([^&#]*))', args.url)` and get `[('v', 'cUjfXWuZySE'), ('list', 'cUjfXWuZySE')]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`urlparse.urlparse`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urlparse) and [`urlparse.parse_qs`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.parse_qs):

```
>>> import urlparse
>>>
>>> url = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cUjfXWuZySE&list=cUjfXWuZySE'
>>> parts = urlparse.urlparse(url)
>>> urlparse.parse_qs(parts.query)
{'list': ['cUjfXWuZySE'], 'v': ['cUjfXWuZySE']}
>>> {name:values[0] for name, values in urlparse.parse_qs(parts.query).iteritems()}
{'list': 'cUjfXWuZySE', 'v': 'cUjfXWuZySE'}
```

Comment: For python 3, you have to use `import urllib.parse as urlparse` as a first line of the example.